# In simplifying an algebraic expression, is it allowed to multiply by $\frac{1/x}{1/x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a rather elementary algebra question regarding simplifying expressions. Suppose I have the following expression:

$$\frac{x}{y}$$

Here, $x$ and $y$ are any algebraic expressions. Is it allowed to multiply both the numerator and denominator by the expressions? For example:

$$\frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

I would say yes, because $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=1$ which means that we multiply our expression by $1$.

Comment: Yes, that preserves the value of the expression

Comment: As long as you make sure $x \neq 0$ then this is valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introducing that factor also introduces the caveat $x\neq 0$, which implicitly accompanies the new expression from this point forward.

This means, for example, that if you do this manipulation in the process of solving some equation, and end up with a solution $x=0$, then this solution must be excluded since it was derived on the condition that in fact $x\neq 0$. The case $x=0$ must be considered separately.

In such a case, it is possible that $x=0$ actually *is* a solution—you just can’t use this manipulation in discovering it.